# Requesting an explanation for the concept of "Binding event handlers to class instance" in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, binding, event-handling

Hi I'm new to full stack web development, and I'm trying to understand the concept *“Binding event handlers to class instance” in React*

```js
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // <- why?
  }
  
  handleClick(event){
    // your event handling logic
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <button type="button" 
      onClick={this.handleClick}>
      Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Comment: what part of binding do you require explanation?

Answer (score 1):

React docs https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as `onClick={this.handleClick}`, you should bind that method.

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
  }
    
  handleClick(event){
    console.log(this); // 'this' is undefined
  }
    
  render(){
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

To resolve you can bind `this` to the function on the class constructor

```
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); 
  }
```

or public class fields syntax (arrow functions)

```
class Foo extends React.Component{
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this); 
  }
 
  render(){
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```